# Сортирует ли примитивы коллекции HashSet()?

Tags: java, хеширование, коллекции

```
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

public class Main2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Set<Integer> intset = new HashSet<Integer>();
        intset.add(1);
        intset.add(2);
        intset.add(35);
        intset.add(42);
        intset.add(5);
        intset.add(6);
        intset.add(7);
        intset.add(832);
        intset.add(9);
        intset.add(1000);
        intset.add(11);
        intset.add(12);
        intset.add(13);
        intset.add(14);
System.out.println("hash set: "+intset);

    }

}
// Output:
// hash set: [1, 2, 5, 6, 7, 9, 11, 12, 13, 14, 35, 42, 832, 1000]
```

Comment: Версию своей явы скажите, буду фокусы показывать :) На 1.8_74 не воспроизводится.

Comment: java 1.8.0.72, я тоже думаю что связано с версиями java )

Comment: замечу, что в момент добавления это уже совсем не примитивы

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Итак, дорогие мои. Отвечаю на собственный вопрос. Все мы ми знаем, или не все, что HashSet это тотже самое что и HashMap, только у HashSet -> values всегда null. Когда мы инициализируем HashSet или HashMap с конструктором по умолчанию, то создается масив на 16 корзин в котором будет содержатся "информация"(!) о hashCode об*єкта ключа, которая будет соответствовать індексу корзины масива, где и будет содержатся ссылка на цельный об*ект(пара(ключ и значение)).
Логически получается следующее, что если вы будете в качестве об*екта ключа использовать клас Integer со значением в диапазоне от 0 - 15, то hashCode вам вернет само значение об*єкта Integer, а это значение и будет индексом корзины в масиве к которому и будет привязана ссылка на целестный об*ект(пара(ключ и значение)).

Answer (score 8):

Нет, не сортирует. Вам просто повезло, что числа оказались упорядочены *на вашей версии Java*. Вероятно, это связано с тем, что на вашей версии над хэшкодом не делается дополнительных преобразований, а хэшкод целого числа — это само число. Но никто не гарантирует, будут делаться преобразования или нет. Естественно, алгоритм хэширования не стохастический: если один раз получилось упорядочено, то и другой раз получится. Но тем не менее никто не гарантирует, что порядок сохранится на другой машине или в другой версии Java. К примеру, Oracle JDK 7u60 выдаёт:

```
>"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_60\bin\java.exe" Main2
hash set: [1000, 35, 1, 832, 2, 5, 6, 7, 42, 9, 11, 12, 13, 14]
```

А Oracle JDK 8u60 выдаёт:

```
>"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_60\bin\java.exe" Main2
hash set: [832, 1, 2, 35, 5, 6, 7, 1000, 9, 42, 11, 12, 13, 14]
```

У вас, наверно, какая-нибудь Java на андроиде, в которой своя библиотека классов (порождённая Apache Harmony). В других версиях Java порядок может отличаться.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Перетестил на других версиях Java, действительно виводит не отсортированую колекцию)

Answer (score 7):

Когда вы конкатенируете `HashSet` со строкой (`"hash set: "+intset`), коллекция приводится к строковому типу неявным вызовом метода `toString()`.

Сам метод `toString()` определен в классе `java.util.AbstractCollection`, который, в свою очередь, для перечисления элементов коллекции обращается к `java.util.HashSet#iterator`. И вот, что говорит JavaDoc этого метода:

```
/**
 * Returns an iterator over the elements in this set.  The elements
 * are returned in no particular order.
 */
```

То есть итерация по элементам множества не обещает какой-либо конкретный порядок. Кроме того в самом начале JavaDoc класса `HashSet` мы видим:

> It makes no guarantees as to the iteration order of the set; in particular, it does not guarantee that the order will remain constant over time.

То есть **никаких гарантий** на порядок обхода вообще **нет**, а если вы заметили какой-то порядок, то он может в следующий раз быть другим.

Comment: честно говоря оно и при обычном System.out.println(intset); виводит тотже результат.          даже при переборе hashSet() через цикл for-each получаем ожинаковий вариант, при множественном запуске.

Comment: `System.out.println(intset)` так же неявно вызывает intset.toString().